# Message Description Popup while sending message to same network in CMD

Tags: windows, cmd

I want to send message from Dell-PC to Acer-PC
Both are connected to same wifi network.
Dell-PC - Windows 10
Acer-PC - Windows 7

But when ever i use msg command, i get the following:-

[image]

The command i use:-
`msg /SERVER:Acer-PC * /TIME:20 "Welcome!"`

Comment: The `msg` command is for sending messages to users logged on to the same computer, as in Terminal Services (Since XP you are a user on a one user terminal server which is why you can send messages to yourself - this is how Fast User Switching was implemented). You may not affect a logged on user on another computer. This could be used as a denial of service attack OR a really annoying IT Dept if it was allowed. It used to be allowed and it was abused

Comment: Oh, ok. Thanks. Is there any other alternative way?

Comment: Email. A program (a batch file even) on both computers. Sending a file.

Comment: I cannot use that in my app

Comment: I dont want to install any app or open any website on another pc.

Comment: You can't do it then.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is an hybrid of Batch and VBScript

You will need to enable LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy value in remote computer:
In that computer open CMD as administrator and type:

```
reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

It should return `The operation completed successfully.`

Next, create the message box file. For that use a tool called PsExec from [Windows Sysinternals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec)

When you have downloaded PsExec, run the following command:

`PsExec \\Acer-PC -e CMD /c echo CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Popup "Welcome!",20,"" ^> C:\MessageBox.vbs`

To run the message box, type the following from your computer (Acer-PC):
`PsExec \\Acer-PC -e WScript.exe C:\MessageBox.vbs`

It will appair the message during 20 seconds

Comment: Thanks, sorry for late reply. I will try and tell the results